# cameltest case with bean

Tags: apache-camel, junit4, spring-batch

In my java class i have something like below:

```
from("direct:dcrm:input")
        .routeId("dcrm-route"
        .convertBodyTo(Message.class)

        .setHeader(
                        "recipientListHeader",
                        simple("activemq:"+rdvrQueueName+ ".${body.controllerID}?jmsMessageType=Text&timeToLive="
                                + rdvrMessageTimeToLive 
                                + "&deliveryPersistent=" + deliveryPersistent))     

            .choice()
            .when(simple("${body.messageType} == 'rdvr'"))
            .bean(new DcrmMessageHandler(), "process")
            .marshal(requestMessage)
            .recipientList(header("recipientListHeader"))
            .onPrepare(new MesssageProcessor()).parallelProcessing()
            .end()
            .setBody(constant(StatusCode.SUCCESS))
            .otherwise()
            .endChoice();
```

while writing Junit i am doint like this :

```
 @Test
        public void testSendMatchingMessage() throws Exception {
            String expectedBody = "<matched/>";

            resultEndpoint.expectedBodiesReceived(expectedBody);

            template.sendBodyAndHeader(expectedBody, "recipientListHeader", 0);

            resultEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied();
        }


    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        //return new DcrmOutboundRoute();
        return new RouteBuilder() {

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                from("direct:dcrm:input")
                .filter(header("recipientListHeader").isEqualTo(constant(StatusCode.SUCCESS)))
                .bean(new DcrmMessageHandler(), "process").to("mock:result");
            }
        };
    }
```

But I am getting the bellow error:

java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/persistence/NoResultException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)

Answer (score 0):

Check your classpath or your Maven dependencies, in particular the one referencing JPA (javax.persistence). You should have a dependency with groupId javax.persistence and probably artifactId persistence-api, replace it by org.hibernate.javax.persistence or org.eclipse.persistence dependency.